# Links working on Index Page on local but not when deployed

Tags: razor, azure-web-app-service

Got a weird issue.  On the Index page on [this website](https://proexcelsolutions.com) the links work when on local deployment but when published they do not.

I made a copy of the Index page and renamed to [Default](https://proexcelsolutions.com/Default).  When I go to that all the links work.

Everywhere else on the site the links work.  It is just in the Index Page.  It is being hosted on Azure.

I have tried swapping links from asp-page to href with the same result

Any ideas?

Comment: Page routing can be funny business when it goes wonky ☺. I see that your root is being redirected to /Default. Is Index.razor under /Pages? Any custom routing in Startup.cs?

Comment: Can you show me the Index page?  I think it maybe something wrong in your page .